# Did the System Lords have terrestrial animals on their colonies?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The Goa'uld like to have human hosts (though not necessarily exclusively), and their colony worlds are frequently populated with pine trees- do said colonies also have other animals from Earth such as cattle, horses or sheep (or even animals who *aren't* hoofed quadrupeds)?

Comment: Ra had a cat on his ship in the film.

Comment: Goats; https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifices

Comment: Dogs; https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Dog

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

In the episode [Emancipation](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Emancipation), the transplanted Mongol tribes ride horses.

There is mention in a late episode of a Jaffa ritual that requires a goat for sacrifice.

Given the diversity of cultures and time periods from which Human populations were borrowed for Goa'uld colonies, it's safe to speculate that they'd bring at least some of their herd/pack animals with them, since the marginal cost to the System Lords would've been basically nil.

Comment: Is it a 'goat goat' or a 'space goat'? There's mention of a goatlike creature called a goat but that's clearly not a goat in another episode...